# Externalizing Spring Security configuration?

Tags: java, web-applications, spring-security, jndi

I have a web application that works with several different configurations of Spring Security already.  However, these difference configuration are all setup within my applicationContext configuration file.  Therefore, in order to tweak these at a customer site, these would have to be modified INSIDE the WAR file.  If customers manually modify the WAR file, then they'll lose their changes after redeploying a new WAR.

Is there a way to externalize this configuration?  Is there a way I can load the configuration using JNDI somehow?

Answer (score 4):

It's an interesting question. Since Spring Security should be configured in root webapp context, you can't externalize its configuration to other contexts. Also you can't change the set of config resources from inside the context. So, you should do it from outside:

- You can use a well-known file system location:

  ```
   <context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>
           /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
           file:///C:\config.xml
       </param-value>
   </context-param>
  ```
- System properties are resolved in `contextConfigLocation`, so you can use it:

  ```
   <context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>
           /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
           file:///${configPath}
       </param-value>
   </context-param>
  ```

  and `-DconfigPath=...`
- You can override `XmlWebApplicationContext.getResource()` and implement whatever you want:

  ```
  public class MyXmlWebApplicationContext extends XmlWebApplicationContext {
      private static final String JNDI_PREFIX = "jndi:/";        
      @Override
      public Resource getResource(String location) {
          if (location.startsWith(JNDI_PREFIX)) return getJndiResource(location);
          else return super.getResource(location);
      }
      protected Resource getJndiResource(String location) { ... }
  }
  ```

  and

  ```
  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
          /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
          jndi:/...
      </param-value>
  </context-param>        
  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
      <param-value>com.example.MyXmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
  </context-param>
  ```

Comment: If I were to go the JNDI route, I assume I would have to programmatically configure spring security, yes?

Comment: BTW - I am concerned about the idea of opening a file on the file system.  I am not sure that some customers will allow this in a JEE environment, and also I am unsure as to how this will interplay with clustering.

Comment: @HDave: No, the third approach shows how you can create your own way to access XML configs (as well as other `Resource`s).

Comment: I think I get it.  So the getResource uses a JNDI name to retrieve the JNDI object which is an XML String, yes?

Comment: @HDave: Yes, you may implement it this way if your application server supports it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, which references an external file, then use the ${key} syntax without your Spring configuration files to reference key/value pairs in the externalized property file.

Another solution is to specify an absolute path in your web.xml to reference a Spring contextConfigLocation.

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/absolute_path/ldap.xml, /WEB-INF/context/dao-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: I am familiar with that capability, but I don't think I can use it to add/remove an LDAP server authentication provider to the list of authentication providers, for example.

Comment: You can't use this mechanism to configure providers.  Another approach is to create an externalized security context XML file.  You can reference files outside your war with Spring.

Comment: Bacman -- this sounds interesting - can you provide a hint on how to reference externalized context XML file?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use org.springmodules.commons.configuration.CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean to store and retrieve your configuration as key, value pair in database table

```
    <bean name="DatabaseConfiguration" class="org.apache.commons.configuration.DatabaseConfiguration">
            <constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <constructor-arg index="1" value="CONFIG_TABLE_NAME"/>
            <constructor-arg index="2" value="KEY_COLUMN_NAME"/>
            <constructor-arg index="3" value="VALUE_COLUMN_NAME"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Here is the full configuration

Answer (score 0):

Spring comes with a couple of options for externalizing
Spring configuration details into property files that can be managed outside of the
deployed application:

1. Property placeholder configurers replace placeholder variables placed in property
   values with values from an external properties file.
2. Property overriders override bean property values with values from an external
   properties file. In addition, the open source Jasypt project
   offers alternative implementations ofS pring’s property placeholder configurer and overrider that can pull those values from encrypted properties files.
   A placeholder configurer can be configured like this for classpath

   A placeholder configurer can be configured like this for filepath
    
   if db.properties contains as follows 
   jdbc.driverClassName=DriverclassName
   jdbc.url=Driverclass://localhost/applicationname/
   jdbc.username=test
   jdbc.password=test1
   Now we can replace the hardcoded values in the Spring configuration with place-holder       variables based on the properties in db.properties

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you want modify authorizations, you can use Requestmap and save all the authorization configurations in database, then deliver different versions with external bootstrap data definitions.