# Spring configuration from database

Tags: java, spring

We have an application which is deployed 120 times with slightly different configurations for each. We would like the configuration to be stored in the database for auditing and management purposes.

How can you instantiate Spring beans directly from the database without using XML?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to keep the bean configuration for connecting to the database in the database...?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't have zero XML config (unless you use JavaConfig, which doesn't make things different in your case) . You can externalize some of it to the database, and use a custom `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/java/SpringWithCommonConfig.aspx) on how to achieve this.

Comment: Well, you *can* have zero XML config, if you use the new `@Configuration`/`@Bean` style.

Answer (score 2):

@Bozho's suggestion is almost certainly the most practical solution, especially if the differences between the deployments is minimal and can be expressed via simple scalar properties.

The alternative is to write your own `BeanFactory` implementation. This is a non-trivial exercise, and you want to be sure that it's what you need. A good starting point would be to look at the source for `XmlBeanFactory`, and then write your own (`DatabaseBeanFactory`, perhaps) which does something similar, but fetching the bean definitions from the database, rather than from local XML files.

It's going to be quite a lot of extra work, though.

Answer (score 2):

There are some options which are simplier than skaffman's suggestion:

- If your configuration is stored in the database in XML form, you can implement a custom resource fetching strategy by overriding `AbstractApplicationContext.getResource()`, so that you can load XML configs from the database. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805424/externalizing-spring-security-configuration/3805915#3805915) for some sample code. Using this approach you can also generate XML config on the fly.
- If your configuration is stored in the "disassembled" form, you can build `BeanDefinition`s and add them to the `BeanDefinitionRegistry` during initialization of the context using one of the following approaches:

  - Implement a [namespace extension](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html)
  - Implement a [`BeanFactoryPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html) (you will need to downcast `ConfigurableListableBeanFactory` to `BeanDefinitionRegistry`, which work for most of application contexts types)
  - Since Spring 3.0.1 the previous approach was rectified by introduction of [`BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html)

Answer (score 2):

In case of Web Application:

Write custom ServletContextListener implementation that populates Properties instance with the database values on application startup and passes it to the Spring's PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. See this post for complete working example: http://blog.javaforge.net/post/31720600427/configuring-spring-based-web-application-from-database