# Design options for Spring Batch implementation

Tags: java, spring-batch

We are to replace a legacy scheduler implementation written in PL/SQL in a large enterprise environment and I'm evaluating Spring Batch for the job.

Although the domain is pretty close to the one provided by Spring Batch, there are few subtleties we have to address before deciding to embark on Spring Batch.

One of them has to do with **jobs**. In our domain, a job can be one of two things: **a shell script** or **a stored procedure**. Jobs and steps definitions are stored in a **table** in the **database**. Before each execution, they are instanciated into another table similiar to job_execution table in Spring Batch.

There are hundreds of jobs and thousands of steps. Keeping and managing these in xml files don't seem like a viable option. We'd like to continue to manage jobs description in tables.

So what are our options to CRUD jobs definitions at **runtime** and in a **database**?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you're out of luck. Following suggestions are hardly worth the effort for you in my opinion.

- Your jobs are brought to limited amount of parameterized templates that are predefined and filled from DB on (parallel) execution.
- You develop a tool that creates configuration from DB on request.

e.g. [Spring configuration from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913064/spring-configuration-from-database)