# How to handle Spring application configuration?

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I have standalone Spring application that has its setting in DMBS. I have an idea to use only one code (that specifies particular instance) when application is starting and application reads own setting from database. Setting values are then used for creating beans in applicationContext XML file and later in beans itself.

So far (developing phase) I used one properties file and read it in such way:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/taskproducer.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

What is the best way how to handle setting from database in Spring application?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3913145/2231632

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring configuration from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913064/spring-configuration-from-database)

Comment: @user2148736, if one of the answer suits your needs it would be nice if you could mark that one as correct + upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

You are heading the right way. Property files should indeed contain the database configuration properties.

If you want to go one-step further, you can have profile-specific property files, e.g. development-specific configuration and production-specific.

Take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3l5awQGo8XA) video for some nice instructions on this subject.

**EDIT:** in case I misunderstood, and you wanted some guidance on how to setup your database using these properties, [here](https://gist.github.com/gabrielruiu/dbe7dfb5d6910ce4a541) is an example of a Spring XML configuration, based on properties from a configuration file.

Short mention: for example, you would setup your DataSource like this:

```
   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>
```

Then in your property file you would have defined the following properties:

```
database.url=http://localhost:3306/mydb
database.username=sa
database.password=
```

Hope this is helpful

Comment: While the link is pretty useful, IMO this answer is not exactly solving the issue that's reported.

Comment: As far as I could tell he wanted some guidance on using enviroment properties in general. I apologize if I misunderstood.

Comment: Added an example for configuring the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a configurer bean which reads props from DB

```
class DbProperties extends java.util.Properties {
    DbProperties() {
        String v1 = ... // read prop from db
        setProperty("p1", "v1");
    }   
}
```

add it to Spring context

```
...
    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean id="c1" class="DbProperties" />
    <bean id="b1" class="B1"/>

    <!--  
    <context:property-placeholder location="taskproducer.properties" />
    -->
    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="c1"/>
```

and use it

```
class B1 {
    @Value("${p1}")
    int x;
}
```